# Pyqt .py to .ui

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

(pyqt5, not pyside2) I have seen people in pyqt designer save their .ui file and turn it into a .py file and then edit the .py file and their changes some how show up in the pyqt designer

Could anyone explain to me how to do that? Or maybe what should I install??

Comment: I sincerely doubt you've exactly seen that, mostly because even if it's *theoretically* possible to "regenerate" an ui file (through QAbstractFormBuilder), it's not reliable and doesn't work with complex or custom widgets. Note that if you're asking this because you're editing pyuic files and you don't want them overwritten, you're asking a wrong question, as those files are **not meant** for that, and the only proper way to use them is to import them *unmodified*, as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before, but personally, I did it like this:
I make my interface with Qt designer then I convert the .ui to .py with a batch

```
@python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic "myUi.ui" -o "myUi.py" -x
```

I never modify the generated .py, I prefer to modify the .ui and then convert it back again.
In my project, I import the Ui class present in "myUi.py".
I hope this will help you.